# How do I add items to String ArrayList when I click on RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I want to add the textview text from my RecyclerView item to an ArrayList when I click on RecyclerView item.

I created an ArrayList of strings.

```
class HobbiesAdapter(val hobbyItem: HobbiesClass) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
    var list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.hobbynameTV.text = hobbyItem.hobbyName
        Picasso.get().load(hobbyItem.imageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.hobbyImageView)

        //On click listener whenever an item of RecyclerView is pressed
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            list.add(viewHolder.itemView.hobbynameTV.text.toString())
            Log.d("list ",list.toString())
        }

}

override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.row
}

}
```

[image: recyclerview]

When I press on Caffe's "list: [Caffe's]" appears on my Logcat but when I click another item for example the one that says Camping. On my Logcat it says list: [Camping] not list: [Caffe's,Camping]
So Caffe's gets removed. How do I fix this. I want every item that I press to appear on my arraylist not only the last one I pressed

**Edit**

I applied the solutions provided but I still get only one element in my list it does not matter if I pressed all the elements in my recyclerview it only shows the last added element.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to store only a selected item then you must clear a list before adding another item in the list.

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        list.clear()
        list.add(viewHolder.itemView.hobbynameTV.text.toString())
        Log.d("list ",list.toString())
    }
```

Try This...

Comment: I want to store every item that I press. For example if I press Caffe's then Camping and then Restaurants I want my list to have all three items.

Comment: Then in that case remove `list.clear()` from above solution.